# Popular open source JavaScript projects using Facebook Flow (type checker)?

Tags: javascript, typechecking

Could you please indicate some popular open source JavaScript systems that are using Facebook/Flow https://flowtype.org/ ?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." - [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)